# Why does std::cout not print values from union, but printf does?

Tags: c++, printf, cout

In the following code `std::cout` does not print the values, but `printf` does. Why is this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

struct bits
{
    union
    {
        unsigned char b;
        struct
        {
            unsigned char b0:1, b1:1, b2:1, b3:1, b4:1, b5:1, b6:1, b7:1;
        };
    };
};

const union
{
    bits b[3];
    char c[3];
} CU = { .c = { -1, 0, 1 }};


int main()
{
    std::cout << "----- chars:\n";

    std::cout << "\tstd::cout (c): " << CU.c[0]
                 << ", " << CU.c[1]
                 << ", " << CU.c[2] 
                             << "\n";

    printf("\tprintf (c): %d, %d, %d\n", CU.c[0],
                             CU.c[1],
                             CU.c[2]);

    std::cout << "\n----- bits:\n";

    for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        std::cout << "\tstd::cout\n\t\t(bits): [" << i << "] = "
            << CU.b[i].b0 << CU.b[i].b1 << CU.b[i].b2
            << CU.b[i].b3 << CU.b[i].b4 << CU.b[i].b5
            << CU.b[i].b6 << CU.b[i].b7 << "\n";
        std::cout << "\t\t(b): [" << i << "] = " << CU.b[i].b << "\n";

        printf("\tprintf\n\t\t(bits): [%d] = %d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d\n",
            i, CU.b[i].b0, CU.b[i].b1, CU.b[i].b2,
            CU.b[i].b3, CU.b[i].b4, CU.b[i].b5,
            CU.b[i].b6, CU.b[i].b7);
        printf("\t\t(b): [%d] = %d\n\n", i, CU.b[i].b);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
----- chars:
        std::cout (c): �, , 
        printf (c): -1, 0, 1

----- bits:
        std::cout
                (bits): [0] = 
                (b): [0] = �
        printf
                (bits): [0] = 11111111
                (b): [0] = 255

        std::cout
                (bits): [1] = 
                (b): [1] = 
        printf
                (bits): [1] = 00000000
                (b): [1] = 0

        std::cout
                (bits): [2] = 
                (b): [2] = 
        printf
                (bits): [2] = 10000000
                (b): [2] = 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You passed the parameter `%d` to `printf`, telling it to read the value as an `int`, but the same was not done for `std::cout`, so it interprets the values as `char`'s and outputs the characters themselves, not their integer values.

Convert to `int` first:

```
std::cout << "\tstd::cout (c): " << int(CU.c[0])
          << ", " << int(CU.c[1]) << ", " << int(CU.c[2])
          << "\n";
```

Comment: of course ... me looking at the forest and wondering why I keep bumping into trees ...

Answer (score 2):

It has nothing to do with them being in a union.

Streaming a `char` to `cout` will output it as a character, rather than its numerical value; as `printf` would if you specified `%c` rather than `%d`.

The simplest way to print the numerical value of a `char` via `cout` is to convert it to `int`.